# jQuery css appended to iframe for a split second

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So i am making a page where the user have multiple links and when the user clicks the link the iFrame changes the src and shows the user the content.

Now i got this css file which applies to every page in the iframe, instead of applying the css file to every other page (which can be alot) i figured i append my css into the iframe.

But it only works when you are leaving the page and you can see the css for a split second.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //The iframe
    var frameContent = $("#frameContent");    

    $(".SideMenuWrapper a").each(function() {

        //Gets the href for each link so we dont have to write a click event for all the links
        var href = $(this).attr("href");

        $(this).click(function(e) {         
            e.preventDefault();          

            //Applying the css to the iframe
            var head = frameContent.contents().find("head");
            head.append($("<link/>", {rel : "stylesheet", href : "../lib/css/gui.css", type: "text/css"}));

            frameContent.attr('src', href);          
        });
    });  
});
```

I have tried moving the head append under the `frameContent.attr('src', href);` But that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why are you triggering click inside each loop?

Comment: @A.Wolff That's supposed to be commented sorry. Anyway with or without it, same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see it, you should use onload event of iframe:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //The iframe
    var frameContent = $("#frameContent");
    $('.SideMenuWrapper a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Gets the href for each link so we dont have to write a click event for all the links
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        //Applying the css to the iframe

        frameContent.on('load', function () {
            var head = $(this).contents().find("head");
            head.append($("<link/>", {
                rel: "stylesheet",
                href: "../lib/css/gui.css",
                type: "text/css"
            }));
        }).attr('src', href);
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! also thanks for making my links more efficient!

Comment: Just one thing, depending behaviour you are looking for and not sure how each browser handles it, but maybe would be more accurate: `frameContent.one('load',...);` instead of using `on()`. In case you switch iframe src

Comment: Okay i will keep that in mind when im testing on diffrent browsers, thanks